# Turbolinks - Why turbolinks doesn't work with jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

Why Turbolinks does not work when we use jquery or javascript, does it only work with CoffeeScript? Or what if I am using CoffeeScript and any third party library in my Ruby on rails project which is in javascript, does Turbolinks work or not?

Comment: At least say something before downvoting.

Comment: can you specify what is your problem? turbolinks works with javascript and jquery. if you specify what doesn't work for you, we can help you

Comment: @xploshioOn Then why my left sidebar menu is not toggling properly with Turbolinks, but when I remove the Turbolinks it works fine.

Comment: @xploshioOn please see this

Answer (score 1):

Turbolinks works with jQuery and Javascript.

Turbolinks is written in CoffeeScript, but it's compiled to JavaScript.

Reference: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#building-from-source

If you need to disable turbolinks for a specific item, you can add `data-turbolinks="false"` as an attribute.

Example:

```
<a href="menu.html" data-turbolinks="false">My Menu</a>
```

Reference: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#disabling-turbolinks-on-specific-links

The turbolinks documentation provides information on how to integrate with your application: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#building-your-turbolinks-application

Comment: @shashiverma that's a completely different question. You'll need to provide some code examples in your question to dig into this. I added one item to my answer that might help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Your updated answer is also helpful though. So, you are saying that if I use Javascript or jquery or CoffeeScript the Turbolinks will work fine. Ok, I'll contact you when I have an issue regarding this.

Comment: @shashiverma it's not necessarily that it will "work fine", moreso that it works (which was your original question). It's compatible. Where it often breaks down is turbolinks has it's own life cycle hooks (page load, reload, etc) and your jquery or javascript (and any frameworks you're using) might have their own actions that may or may not need to trigger those hooks. The answer is more "yes, you can use them all together but you may need to write some code". If you have specific issues with code samples please do post a new question I'm sure someone can help

Comment: Ok, Thank you, brother.